# SQL delete query takes too long

Tags: sql-server, left-join, sql-delete, linked-server, not-exists

I use either query 1:

```
    delete dp
    from [linkedserver\sqlserver].[test].[dbo].[documentpos] dp
    where not exists (
    select 1 from document d where d.GUID = dp.documentguid
    )
```

or query 2:

```
    DELETE cqdp 
    FROM [linkedserver\sqlserver].[test].[dbo].[documentpos] cqdp
    left join Document cqd on cqd.GUID = cqdp.DocumentGUID
    where cqd.guid is null
```

Both queries do the same, but take too long. I've canceled the execution after 2 days.

This is the estimated execution plan for both queries:

[image: estimated execution plan]
[image]

I've also other queries which use the same linked server and those don't take this long. But apparently there is a problem with the linked server (remote scan 98% of time). What can I do to reduce the cost of remote scan?

Comment: I've had issues with linked server efficiencies in the past. Have you tried to bring the records in `Document` (maybe by inserting into a temp table `#`) into the `[linkedserver\sqlserver].[test]` database and then run your `DELETE` SQL statement there?

Comment: Have you tried using `OPENQUERY` ? Most of the time this gives you better execution times.

You could also be missing some indexes on foreign key columns. You could drop and recreate the foreign keys to speed up deletes. 
But only when you are in control of all connections.(Single user mode)

Comment: Delete in batches? `DELETE TOP 1000...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT GUID
 INTO [linkedserver\sqlserver].[test].[dbo].[temp_guids]
 FROM document 
  

DELETE cqdp 
FROM [linkedserver\sqlserver].[test].[dbo].[documentpos] cqdp
left join [linkedserver\sqlserver].[test].[dbo].[temp_guids] cqd on cqd.GUID = cqdp.DocumentGUID
where cqd.guid is null
```